# How to add 2 hours to a date field

Tags: db2

I'm working with DB2 database in which the time field is the following string:

> 12104102000000

where it means, from the left:

```
> 1 --> is the century 21 --> is the year 04 --> is the month 10 --> are
> the hours 20 --> are the minutes 00 --> are the seconds 000 --> are
> the milliseconds
```

Well, the problem is that this field is synchronized with the reference time, so respect to Italy (where I'm working) is two hours back.

I have a query where usually I extract the date field with substr function and the starting part is:

```
select substr("Message_Time",4,2) || '/' || substr("Message_Time",6,2)  || '/' || '20' || substr("Message_Time",2,2) as "Date",
       substr("Message_Time",8,2) || ':' || substr("Message_Time",10,2) as "Hour"
```

I need to add to hour substr only, the 2 hour to bring the date to Italy.
But I think the issue is at the change of the day, because if I have e.g. 20th of April, 22:40, it corrisponds to 21st of April, 00:40 in Italy.

How should I do in order to make it working?

Comment: My advice is to give up on this and stop storing your dates this way.  Instead, use a formal DB2 date column.  There are all sorts of ugly edge cases you will encounter if you try to make your current question work.

Comment: It consists of an official database of a monitoring product in a working environment. I can't change this.

Answer (score 0):

Please tag which DB2 you use.

If DB2LUW or DB2 for I, you can use

`to_date('12104102000000', 'YYYMMDDHH24MISSFF1') - 100 YEARS + CURRENT TIMEZONE`

I guess it works with DB2 for Z but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you want your result to be in the same string form:

```
SELECT
   SUBSTR (D, 1, 1)
|| SUBSTR 
  (
    TO_CHAR
    (
      TO_DATE(CAST(19 + SUBSTR(D, 1, 1) AS CHAR(2)) || SUBSTR(D, 2), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF3') + 2 HOURS
    , 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF3'
    )
  , 3
  )
FROM (VALUES '12104102240000') T (D)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT your_date_column + (quantity HOURS) AS new_date
FROM your_table;
```

Replace `your_date_column` with the column containing your date and `your_table` with the table name. You can adjust the quantity as needed to add a different number of hours.

For example, to add two hours to a date column, you can use:

```
SELECT your_date_column + (2 HOURS) AS new_date
FROM your_table;
```